# Using cdn of react-select in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, react-select

I want to use react-select with cdn. I tried downloading cdn into react-select but I keep getting error as select is not defined.

I tried to download the zip package of react-select with but I dont know how to use it.

Following is how I did it.

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-select/5.7.3/index-2ce68625.prod.min.js" type="module"></script>
```

and in js file I want to import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the dependencies

[EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/Binal-Ajudiya/pen/RweOYJR)

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16.7.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emotion@9.2.12/dist/emotion.umd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16.7.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.5.10/prop-types.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-input-autosize@2.2.1/dist/react-input-autosize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-select@2.1.2/dist/react-select.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks ! I have a question Like I am using Select on another file how to import it into the js file.

Comment: Can you brief how you want to use it in JS? or share your code about what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: Here is my code and I want is to use select in stepper file.
source code :- https://github.com/rajivchaulagain/stepper-react
live url:- https://rajivchaulagain.github.io/stepper-react/